# c++ while(getline (file,str)) doesnt work

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, getline

I am trying to read from a file to populate 2d vector (vector of vectors).

```
void readFromFile()
    {
        string str;
        ifstream fileToOpen("test.txt");
        if (fileToOpen.is_open())
        {
            resetBoard();
            height=count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileToOpen),istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');
            length=height*2-1;
            cout<<board.size()<<endl;
            while(getline(fileToOpen,str))
            {
                cout<<"inside while\n";
                stringstream ss(str);
                int i;
                vector<short unsigned> line;
                while (ss>>i)
                {
                    line.push_back(i);
                }
                board.push_back(line);
            }
            fileToOpen.close();
            //board.shrink_to_fit();
        }
        else
            cout<<"Unable to open file!\n";
        print();

    }
```

You can ignore most of the code that doesn't relate to actual file opening and reading/writing into vector. Problem is first while loop doesnt seem to execute

```
    while(getline(fileToOpen,str))
    {
        cout<<"inside while\n";
```

cout statement never triggers and I just cant figure out why is this happening, I have attempted using completely new vector, instead of using one I have in class, different printing methods and so on until I figured out it never actually gets to that point

my text file

```
0000000000000001000000000000000
0000000000000011100000000000000
0000000000000110010000000000000
0000000000001101111000000000000
0000000000011001000100000000000
0000000000110111101110000000000
0000000001100100001001000000000
0000000011011110011111100000000
0000000110010001110000010000000
0000001101111011001000111000000
0000011001000010111101100100000
0000110111100110100001011110000
0001100100011100110011010001000
0011011110110011101110011011100
0110010000101110001001110010010
1101111001101001011111001111111
```

Comment: After calling `std::count()` using the stream iterators, the position in the stream is at the end. What was the point of using `length` or `height`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 those variables are global class variables and used outside the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's at eof after the height=count(...) line.

Before the while (getline) add:

```
fileToOpen.seekg(0, fileToOpen.beg);
```

Comment: Note that for file streams this isn't actually guaranteed to refill the buffer with anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
height=count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileToOpen),istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');
```

That exhausts the entire file. So after that, there are no more lines to read. So clearly, a call to getline or any other input function will fail.

You could clear the errors in the stream and reset it back to the beginning, but why do you even need that line in the first place? Just count lines as you read them with `getline`. Or simply get it from `board.size()` after you are done reading (here I am assuming that `board` is a standard sequence container, and that it is empty beforehand).

Comment: that's something I did in very beginning thinking I will need number of lines at the start, but ended up not needing it immediately , thou would never figured that it was the cause